# How do you read POST data from a servlet into a ZipStream?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, stream, zip

The situation is that a ZIP file has been POSTed to a Tomcat server and since it has no parameter name associated with it, we're going right to the request's stream.

```
  ServletInputStream sis = request.getInputStream()
  ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(sis)
  ZipEntry zEntry = zis.getNextEntry()
  while (zEntry != null) {
    // do something with zEntry
    zEntry = zis.getNextEntry()
  }
```

Compellingly simple, but it doesn't work.  It never enters the while loop because the first zEntry is null.  (The ZIP file is valid, btw)

Any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT: Type is multipart/form-data ("multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8ce556d90e9deb6")

Comment: What's the request body encoding? `multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *EDIT: Type is multipart/form-data ("multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8ce556d90e9deb6")*

You need to use a `multipart/form-data` parser to extract the uploaded file. You shouldn't feed it raw to the `ZipInputStream`. It however surprises me that it didn't threw an exception that it's not in ZIP file format.

The [`getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) and consorts are designed for `application/www-form-urlencoded` requests only. They will all return `null` on `multipart/form-data` requests. You need to use [`getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) method instead. Or, when you're still on Servlet 2.5 or older, then you need to parse the body with help of [Apache Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload).

Either way, you should be able to iterate over `multipart/form-data` items and get the uploaded file(s) as an `InputStream` which you in turn read using `ZipInputStream`.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)